# How to Get MAX from Each Group in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

1)

> q3_ReasonYearWise = FOREACH q3_SelectedColumnForReason GENERATE
>   GetYear(application_dt) as Application_Year, loan_purpose;

2)

> q3_Group_Reason_Year = GROUP q3_ReasonYearWise BY (Application_Year,
>   loan_purpose);

3)

> q3_Count_Reasons_Yearwise = FOREACH q3_Group_Reason_Year GENERATE
>   group as me, COUNT(q3_ReasonYearWise.(Application_Year, loan_purpose))
>   as tot;

### Till 3 Step it works fine. And after running step 3 My output is

```
(2007,car)      5
(2007,house)    1
(2007,other)    53
(2007,moving)   6
(2007,medical)  2

(2008,car)      41
(2008,house)    16
(2008,other)    208
(2008,moving)   20
(2008,medical)  27
(2008,wedding)  44
(2008,vacation) 9

(2009,car)      170
(2009,house)    60
(2009,other)    595
(2009,moving)   58
(2009,medical)  84
(2009,wedding)  132
(2009,vacation) 26
```

---

So After this how to find Max for Each Year. My Output must be like...

```
(2007, Other)   53
(2008,other)    208
(2009,other)    595
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this?

1. Include Application_Year also in the 3 stmt
2. GROUP by application year
3. Sort the bags by count in desc order
4. Get the top element
5. Print the groupname and count

q3_Count_Reasons_Yearwise = FOREACH q3_Group_Reason_Year GENERATE **q3_ReasonYearWise.Application_Year as my_application_year**,group as me, COUNT(q3_ReasonYearWise.(Application_Year, loan_purpose)) as tot;

At the end of your 3rd stmt your output should be like this,

```
2007    (2007,car)      5
2007    (2007,house)    1

2008    (2008,car)      41
2008    (2008,house)    16
```

After that  do like this .

```
A = GROUP q3_Count_Reasons_Yearwise BY my_application_year;
B = FOREACH A {
                sortByMax = ORDER q3_Count_Reasons_Yearwise  BY tot DESC;
                topMax = LIMIT sortByMax 1;
                GENERATE FLATTEN(topMax.$1),FLATTEN(topMax.$2);
                }
DUMP B;
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't worked. What i want to achive is MAX(COUNT(tot)) <i.e> Nested Grouping is it possible in PIG

Comment: The above script will work what you want to achieve. Can you paste your pigscript from load stmt to step3 and also sample inputs data?